# How to use com.android.internal.telephony.Phone

Tags: android

I'm new developer on android. What I needed in purpose to use com.android.internal.telephony? Downloading ? Special permissions ?

Comment: There is no `com.android.internal.telephony` in the Android SDK. Hence, unless you are creating your own custom firmware, you should not be using it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the following lines in your `Manifest`, inside of the application tag:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony">
</uses-feature>
```

Also particular features require special `Permissions`, for example sending and receiving sms requires:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" >
</uses-permission>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you answer. But I get yet: "com.android.internal.telephony.gsm cannot resolved". What I need to do to import it into application ? Which API level is required ? (now I use API 10) Thanks

Comment: You're using wrong package name, correct one is: `android.telephony` of course it is supported since API level 1, as it is one of the most important things that phones should do. (But particular features require newest API, like for example `SMSManager` supporting both CDMA and GSM is there since API level 4). Look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/package-summary.html, and you should always search on google and developer.android.com before asking a question.